# numbers in an array add to a specific number java

Tags: java

what is the most efficient way to check if any numbers in an array sum up to specific number for example: an array of (5,3,3,9,4) I want to know if any of these numbers in the array can be added to give 10
this will happen when I add (3,3,4)

Comment: There is a thread about this here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532957/to-find-a-subset-from-a-set-whose-sum-equals-to-zero

Comment: You've described the [Subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)

Comment: Do you only have positive numbers?

Comment: 1) What have you tried? People are more likely to help you if you show you put some effort in it. 2) Looping through the permutations of a short array like that isn't that heavy. There are only `5! = 120`. Every iteration, begin on array index 0 and through the array, adding the values to a `total` value until you reached the end of the array or went above the desired number (10, in this case).

Comment: @RobWatts yes I have only positive numbers

Comment: What other constraints do you have? Will it always be 10? How many numbers might you have? How efficient do you need it to be?

Comment: @11684 This is a part of my solution to a problem the problem says that the array can reach 2000 number so classical solutions will exceed the time limit ! but I'll try on it

Comment: With a 2000 numbers long array you'll have `2000! = :S`. Even google's calculator can't calculate that.

Comment: Doing an n! algorithm on 2000 numbers takes ~10^6000. Completely infeasible.

Comment: @RobWatts I need this solution for this problem is http://www.spoj.com/problems/FARMER/ it won't always be 10 it depends on the user entry The idea is that the array could contain numbers till 2000

Comment: @11684 I want to solve this problem  spoj.com/problems/FARMER in this problem I need to check if the sum of any of the cypress trees in the field is equal to the number of the cypress trees the son can inhert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have to spend more time than I have right now to come up with a really good solution, but I would suggest rethinking your strategy. As @DeepakBala mentioned, you're describing an NP-complete problem.

One thing that makes this different is that the sum (Q) can be significantly larger than the numbers in the array. Additionally, since they're limited to between 3 and 150, when you've got 2000 numbers then you will have a lot of duplicates. Leverage that to your advantage - count the numbers before working with them, and you only have to worry about 149 types of numbers.

To get you thinking about why that matters, consider sorting 1 million numbers 1-100. Just create an array, then count how many times you see each number. Then recreate the list by printing out each number the appropriate number of times. This is O(n) instead of the normal O(n log(n)).

Rather than working with an array of up to 2000 numbers, consider arrays of 150 that tell you about how many of each size you have available and how many of each size you are using.

Try adding all the large numbers until you get within 150 of Q, then seeing if you have any that perfectly make up the difference. If that fails, you'll have to figure out how to go from there.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I did't get the point you mentioned in "Try adding all the large numbers until you get within 150 of Q, then seeing if you have any that perfectly make up the difference. "

Comment: For example, if you have 10 fields of 150, 9 of 149, and 11 of 148, that gives you 4469. If Q is 4600, then you check if you have a field of size 4600-4469=131.