# Finding all possible subset sum which is equal to 0 out of set of positive and negative numbers?

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

You have an array which has a set of positive and negative numbers, print all the subset sum which is equal to 0.

I can think of approach where i can cam make all powersets of givcen array and check if their sum is 0. BUt that does not llok like optimized solution to
me.

After reading looks a bit similar problem on net , looks like it can be solved with dynamic programming like below program to find if there is combination exist
to make sum 11 just an example ?

```
public boolean subsetSum(int input[], int total) {

        boolean T[][] = new boolean[input.length + 1][total + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= input.length; i++) {
            T[i][0] = true;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= input.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= total; j++) {
                if (j - input[i - 1] >= 0) {
                    T[i][j] = T[i - 1][j] || T[i - 1][j - input[i - 1]];
                } else {
                    T[i][j] = T[i-1][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return T[input.length][total];

    }




public static void main(String args[]) {
    TestDynamic ss = new TestDynamic();
   int arr1[] = {2, 3, 7, 8};
    System.out.print(ss.subsetSum(arr1, 11));

}
```

But i am not sure how to extend above programe to

1) Include negative number
2) find combination of elements  whick makes sum as zero( Above program just finds whether its possible to make given sum but does not
find which set of numbers makes it zero)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532957/to-find-a-subset-from-a-set-whose-sum-equals-to-zero

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers solution at the link you provided is not complete and is very high level. I could not understand it atleast

Comment: Try this one: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36214/find-all-subsets-of-an-int-array-whose-sums-equal-a-given-target ;).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full implementation in Javascript. You can run it with node.js.

```
function target_sum(a, k, x)
{
    if (k == a.length) return [];
    if (a[k] == x) {
        return [[a[k]]];
    } else {
        var s = target_sum(a, k + 1, x);        // not using a[k]
        var t = target_sum(a, k + 1, x - a[k]); // using a[k]
        for (var i = 0; i < t.length; ++i) {
            t[i].unshift(a[k]); // a[k] is part of the solution
            s.push(t[i]);       // merge t[] into s[]
        }
        return s;
    }
}

var s = target_sum([1,4,5,2,7,8,-3,-5,-6,9,3,-7,-1,5,6], 0, 0);
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; ++i)
    console.log(s[i].join(","));
```

Note that this is an exponential algorithm. Don't use it on large arrays.

Erwin Rooijakkers also pointed to the right direction. In particular, [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36214/find-all-subsets-of-an-int-array-whose-sums-equal-a-given-target) gives another algorithm. I could be wrong about the following – I believe that algorithm trades speed for space. It avoids staging arrays into the call stack, but it has to do more recursions to achieve that.

EDIT: about the algorithm you mentioned. It is not exponential, but it only works for positive numbers if I am right. Its time complexity is also proportional to the target sum, which may not be ideal depending on input.